# Email Alert when a specific file is available in GCP bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud, gcp-alerts

I need to get an email alert to my email when a specific file in GCP bucket is arrived/available. Which functionality/tool i can use in GCP.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the following approach:

- Use Cloud Functions and specifically the Google Cloud Storage Trigger with the default event `google.storage.object.finalize`. Check out sample code [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage).
- In the function code, you can pass on relevant file details and use a 3rd party email service like SendGrid, etc to send an email. Check out instructions/code here to send out email: https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-enable-real-time-notifications

Comment: Thanks Romin..will check if we can get SendGrid

Comment: Check out this documentation on instructions to send out email via SendGrid. You can take parts of the sample code shown here for your purpose. https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/how-to-enable-real-time-notifications

Answer (score 0):

@Romin solution will work, you can also have a look to Eventarc and Cloud Run.

However, you can use a hack fully managed by Google Cloud.

Firstly, activate the Cloud Storage Audit Logs (be careful, if you have a lot of activity, it can generate a lot of logs and be costly).

Then, create a log based metrics on the audit logs that mentionned the file creation and with the filter on the file path (you can use the =~ operator for regex filtering)

Finally, create an alert on that metrics, and send an email when the alert is triggered

Comment: Hi Guillaume,
Can we use Monitoring Alert on customized scripts output files either shell or python which checks the file in storage bucket or we use monitoring alerts only for audit logs

Comment: No no, it's a ack to let the system generate an automatic alert on a alert config. You can't configure or customize things, it's a raw and automatic email.